# Transfer Windows 7 64-bit system builder to VirtualBox instance on same machine

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, license, oem

Let's suppose I purchase a Windows 7 64-bit system builder license for a particular machine. Sometime next year (or the year after that) when Windows 8 comes out, I'd like to install it on the same machine, replacing Windows 7.

Will I be allowed to install the Windows 7 system builder in VirtualBox running on this same machine?

I've seen various folks on the net claim that if I need to transfer my system builder license I can call Microsoft to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System Builder is an OEM license.  OEM Licenses are not allowed to run in a Virtual Machine.  This is in the license agreement.  If you want to run (or be able to transfer) a license to a virtual machine, you will need to purchase a retail license (or if you're a business, you can purchase a volume license).